# Add cpp file to setuptools but don't compile

Tags: python, pytorch, setuptools

I have a library that I want to publish to PyPi that includes python code and C++ code. The special thing is that the C++ code is loaded via ninja, using

```
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load

lib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
backend = load(
  name="backend",
  sources=[os.path.join(lib_dir, "backend.cpp")],
  verbose=True)
```

My layout:

```
package_name/
  package_name/
    __init__.py
    package.py
    backend.cpp
```

The code above is at the top of `package.py`. This works flawlessly and compiles on the fly, if tested locally.

**BUT**, when packaging this with pypi, the `.cpp` file does not get added. My `setup.py`:

```
setup(
  name='package_name',
  packages=['package_name'],
  ...)
```

I tried:

- adding the `.cpp` as an `Extension`. This causes `setuptools` to try to compile `backend.cpp`, which I don't want, as it won't work (missing headers)
- adding the `.cpp` via `scripts=`. Doesn't seem to do anything.

---

**EDIT** The file shows up in the `.tar.gz` that is produced (in `dist/`). Also if I download it from pypi. *But* it won't show up on disk if I do a `pip install`:

```sh
> tar tvf dist/package_name-0.1.0.tar.gz
...
drwxr-xr-x  0 fabian staff       0 Nov 14 10:17 package_name-0.1.0/package_name/
-rw-r--r--  0 fabian staff     203 Nov 14 09:36 package_name-0.1.0/package_name/__init__.py
-rw-r--r--  0 fabian staff    5569 Nov 14 09:36 package_name-0.1.0/package_name/package.py
-rw-r--r--  0 fabian staff   10101 Nov 12 14:43 package_name-0.1.0/package_name/backend.cpp
...

> ls  /Users/.../miniconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/package_name/
__init__.py
__pycache__
package.py
```

---

**EDIT 2**: It's getting wilder. I tried to add the following to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
  name='package_name',
  packages=['package_name'],
  ext_modules=[CppExtension(
    name='backend',
    sources=['package_name/backend.cpp']),
  ],
  cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExtension.with_options(use_ninja=True)},
  ...
```

And now it's getting built. But it is still not adding the `.cpp` file to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was quite a ride. I don't know what made it finally work, but the following works:

1. put C++ file in a subfolder. I use the following structure:

```
package_name/
  package_name/
    __init__.py
    package.py
    backend/
      backend.cpp
```

2. Use `find_packages()` (pretty sure this is not needed). Final `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
  name='example_package',
  packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
  version='0.1.1',
  description=...,
  long_description=...
  python_requires='>=3.6')
```

Note: no `package_dir`, `package_data`, `data_files` in `setup.py`. No `CppExtension` (we want to build the .cpp on the fly!). No `MANIFEST.in`.